# Install MySql on Windows Azure (using Eclipse)

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-worker-roles

I created a Web Role to install PHP by using Web Plaform Installer (goes well without problem) and I use Eclipse to create a Worker Role to install MySql. Eclipse creates Mysql_WorkerRole.dll (amoung others). following is my .csdef file

```
<WebRole enableNativeCodeExecution="true" name="PhpMySqlWA_phpWebRole">
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="install-php.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="background" />
</Startup>
<Sites>
  <Site name="MyPHPSite" physicalDirectory=".\PhpMySqlWA_phpWebRole">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="HttpEndpoint" endpointName="HttpIn" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
<Imports/>
<Endpoints>
  <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" port="80" protocol="http"/>
</Endpoints>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="StorageAccountName"/>
  <Setting name="StorageAccountKey"/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzureHost"/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzureUserName"/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzurePassword"/>
  <Setting name="SqlAzureDatabase"/>
  <Setting name="UseDataStorage"/>
  <Setting name="UseDevelopmentStorage"/>
  <Setting name="UseCloudStorage"/>
  <Setting name="UseSqlAzure"/>
  <Setting name="LogLevel"/>
  <Setting name="ScheduledTransferPeriodInSeconds"/>
  <Setting name="WindowsAzureStorageConnectionString"/>
  <Setting name="XDrives"/>
  <Setting name="XDrivesLocalCache"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
</WebRole>
<WorkerRole enableNativeCodeExecution="true" name="PhpMySqlWA_MysqlWorkerRole" vmsize="Medium">
<Imports>
  <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
  <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
<LocalResources>
  <LocalStorage cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" name="MySQL" sizeInMB="260"/>
  <LocalStorage cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" name="MySQLDatastore" sizeInMB="60"/>
</LocalResources>
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="InitFile"/>
  <Setting name="LogLevel"/>
  <Setting name="ScheduledTransferPeriodInSeconds"/>
  <Setting name="WindowsAzureStorageConnectionString"/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
 <Endpoints>
   <InternalEndpoint name="MySQL" protocol="tcp"/>
 </Endpoints>
</WorkerRole>
```

when I execute

```
cspack ServiceDefinition.csdef /generateConfigurationFile:ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /role:PhpMySqlWA_MysqlWorkerRole;PhpMySqlWA_MysqlWorkerRole;Mysql_WorkerRole.dll /role:PhpMySqlWA_phpWebRole;PhpMySqlWA_phpWebRole /copyonly
and
csrun ServiceDefinition.csx ServiceConfiguration.cscfg /launchbrowser
```

both web role and worker role is green in Compute Emulator, following is what I see for the worker role

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment17(63).PhpMySqlWA.PhpMySqlWA_MysqlWorkerRole.0
[fabric] Role state Started
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart()
[WaWorkerHost.exe] RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
Information: Mysql_WorkerRole entry point called
Information: Copying folder mysql to C:/Users/ksaleh.CORP/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/d3fdb9aa-    67b5-4dad-9c50-0d5116ded0bc/directory/MySQL/
Information: Copying folder mysql\data to     C:/Users/ksaleh.CORP/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/d3fdb9aa-67b5-4dad-9c50-0d5116ded0bc/directory/MySQLDatastore/
Information: MySQLIP=127.255.0.0
Information: MySQLPort=20001
Information: Copy C:/Users/ksaleh.CORP/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/d3fdb9aa-67b5-4dad-9c50-  0d5116ded0bc/directory/MySQL/my.ini
Information: Starting mysqld C:/Users/ksaleh.CORP/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/d3fdb9aa-67b5-4dad-9c50-0d5116ded0bc/directory/MySQL/bin/mysqld.exe
 Information: Arguments --init-file=C:\\Users\\ksaleh.CORP\\AppData\\Local\\dftmp\\Resources\\d3fdb9aa-67b5-4dad-9c50-0d5116ded0bc\\directory\\MySQL\\
Information: enter looping
Information: Working
```

I change my connectDB.php to use 127.255.0.0:20001 as host (as above) but it generates "Error connecting to database!". I checked event viewer of my machine and found error:

```
C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/dftmp/Resources/d3fdb9aa-67b5-4dad-9c50-0d5116ded0bc/directory/MySQL/bin/mysqld.exe: unknown option '--skip-locking'
```

and it says mysqlid.exe shut down completed

Have I realy installed mysql localy (compute emulator) and if yes why the service has stopped? 
why I cann't connect the database? how can I check everything is ok? 
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I am not sure if you still want to use Windows Azure Web/Worker Role but if you will use Windows Azure WebSite and configure MySQL for your PHP based site, you can get this whole thing working in hours. (I am  looking into your problem now and will add more info later)

Comment: the reason I want to use Web/Worker roles is I have heard and read that VMs on Windows Azure will be recycled sometimes, and we have to take care of our installations of Java/PHP/Mysql automatically by having startup scripts. I have read also about WA websites and watched videos. I think I am confused and miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and your requirement to use Java/PHP/MySQL, I can suggest the best option is to use Windows Azure Virtual Machine rather then using Windows Azure Worker Role.

The Windows Azure Virtual Machine will have advantage over a Worker Role for your project as your don't need to automate the install script and you can manage and scale them same Worker role. Your configuration be as below:

1. Have a Windows Azure VM (Linux or Windows) to Configure your PHP/Java Instance
2. Have a Windows Azure VM (Linux or Windows) to configure your MySQL instance

You can install/configure applications on Virtual Machines by RDP to your instance in Windows VM and with Linux you can use  Putty to install/Configure your applications. These VM are durable so all installation will persist and you don't need to automate any thing on this regard.

When you need more resources just, add more instances to your web instances. I am not sure how will take care of MySQL with multiple instance, this is something you would need to think for future (with both Worker Role and Azure VM).

Here is the starting Point to use Windows Azure VM with Java:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/tutorials/tomcat-on-a-virtual-machine/

Finally if I would have to work on a Java/PHP/MySQL project I would prefer Windows Azure Virtual Machines and (if possible replace MySQL with SQL Azure so I dont need to worry about database scalability however MySQL is also best choice)

Comment: Ok thank you. If I use VMs as you described. what happend when you recycle the virtual machines? do I need to install and configure the application again?

Comment: Nope, Windows Azure Virtual Machines are persisted so you can install anything without being worried for losing the data. Learn more here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj156003

Comment: I read the articles you sent, it is still not clear 100 percent for med, who are going to take care of updating of the Windows Azure Virutal Machines? If I use Windows Azure VM do I need to take care of updates for it like all other host companies? so what is difference with other host companies?